# rake assets:precompile rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...mages/patternbg": expected ")", was ".png) repeat-x ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Can someone quickly direct me on how can I convert this

```
.left-pane {
    ...
    background: url(themes/base/images/patternbg.png) repeat-x #efefef;
    ...
}
```

into

```
.left-pane {
    ...
    background: image-url(themes/base/images/patternbg.png) repeat-x #efefef;
    ...
}
```

I am learning Rails and trying to deploy the application on apache for which I need to use `image-url` instead of `url` in my scss files to load the images (without which they don't) but `rake assets:precompile` throws the following error

> rake assets:precompile rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS
>   after "...mages/patternbg": expected ")", was ".png) repeat-x ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding quotation marks:

```
background: image-url('themes/base/images/patternbg.png') repeat-x #efefef;
```